# Find words and replace with tag wihtin div jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div with some text and I am trying to replace that text with a html tag using jQuery but, its replacing tag as text not as html tag

following is the html structure

```
<h3>Rs.1410 / 30 Tablet(s) </h3>
```

JS which I tried is

```
$("h3").text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace("Rs.", "<i class='fa fa-inr'></i>"); 
});
```

If I try .html() then its replacing all the content within that div which I don't want. Can anybody please suggest

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [**html()**](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function instead of `text()`

```
$("h3").html(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace("Rs.", "<i class='fa fa-inr'></i>"); 
});
```

From the documentation

> A function returning the HTML content to set. Receives the index
>   position of the element in the set and the old HTML value as
>   arguments. jQuery empties the element before calling the function; use
>   the oldhtml argument to reference the previous content. Within the
>   function, this refers to the current element in the set.

Answer (score 0):

no need to use function

```js
$("h3").html(
     $("h3").text().replace("Rs.", "<i class='fa fa-inr'></i>"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Rs.1410 / 30 Tablet(s) </h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
var text = $('h3').html().replace("Rs.", "<i class='fa fa-inr'></i>");
$('h3').html(text);
```

So basically, you are getting the h3 element, calling `.html()` to get its *entire* html contents, using `replace` as you already have and assigning the whole thing to a variable, and then subbing that variable in to another call to `.html()` to replace the existing HTML inside the h3 tag.